Can you use the special use features with tools without the tool?
Relevant Text
[1]

Special Use. Proficiency with a tool usually brings with it a
particular benefit in the form of a special use, as described in this
paragraph.

Weaver's Tools

Repair. As part of a short rest, you can repair a single damaged cloth
object.


I could only find a few exceptions, which explicitly require you to have sufficient materials. But even then, you could just grab those materials without even having the tool on you. Is there additional text that states you have to have the tool to perform such special uses?
This is all assuming the character has proficiency with the said tools.

That is not the intent in the PHB
In the PHB, tools are described as follows (emphases mine):

A tool helps you to do something you couldn't otherwise do, such as craft or repair an item, forge a document, or pick a lock. Your race, class, background, or feats give you proficiency with certain tools. Proficiency with a tool allows you to add your proficiency bonus to any ability check you make using that tool.

It seems clear that if the tool helps you do something "you couldn't otherwise do", that is, that you couldn't do without the tool, then you need the tool to do it.  Merely having the proficiency shouldn't allow you to do something that is not possible without the tool itself.
XGtE is less clear-cut
In addition to tool use checks, XGtE introduces the concept of tool use proficiency influencing the result of other checks, although you might still need the tool itself on hand.
Under "Skills" (78) (emphases mine):

Every tool potentially provides advantage on a check when used in conjunction with certain skills, provided a character is proficient with the tool and the skill.

Here the text also says that not only do you need the proficiency, but you need the tool itself on hand.
Xanathar's, however, also introduces the idea of "special use" properties for tools.
Under "Special Use" (78):

Proficiency with a tool usually brings with it a particular benefit in the form of a special use, as described in this paragraph.

You are correct that the 'special use' rules call out the need for proficiency, but not necessarily the tool itself.  Is this, as you suggest, a specific-over-general exception to the rule that the physical tools are required?  Or is it merely assuming that you are already following the rules for tool use proficiencies, which say that you do need the tools themselves?
The possibility that not every benefit has to be tied to the physical use of the tool itself is also hinted at in the description of Skills (78) (emphasis mine):

the system is mildly abstract in terms of what a tool proficiency represents; essentially, it assumes that a character who has proficiency with a tool also has learned about facets of the trade or profession that are not necessarily associated with the use of the tool.

Honestly, I don't know what RAW is here - but I would suggest that it doesn't really matter.  Tool use is a pretty low-stakes aspect of the game, generally meant to be part of the exploration and social interaction pillars, where DMs generally have more room to decide what seems reasonable for the story, rather than adhering to the stricter rules that govern the more competitive combat pillar.
In the specific case of Weaver's tools that you mention, I think that playing it either way, that tools in hand are required or that they are not, strains verisimilitude in certain circumstances.  I would favor simply having the DM decide whether or not tools were required depending on your actual use scenario.
XGtE (85) says about Weaver's tools:

Components.  Weaver's tools include thread, needles, and scraps of cloth.  You know how to work a loom, but such equipment is too large to transport.

If you insist that the "special use" rules are a specific-over-general exception that means you don't need tools, that does indeed make the special use repair function strange:

Repair.  As part of a short rest, you can repair a single damaged cloth object.

How is your knowledge of weaving supposed to help you accomplish this, absent needle and thread?
On the other hand, insisting that you always need the tools leads to equally strange results, since Weaver's tools proficiency also gives you 'additional insight' when you make Arcana or History checks related to cloth objects, and Investigation checks related to woven items.  Here, I think your knowledge alone would suffice when examining such items, and you and you would not actually need needle and thread.
As a DM, I would likely rule that you do need the tools whenever you are trying to do something, but not when you are trying to know something.
My recommendation would be to simply describe to the DM how your character is using their knowledge, or their tools, or both to accomplish some goal, and let them rule on the results of your actions, as always.

You need the tool to use it
The rules for tools on p. 154 PH say

Proficiency with a tool allows you to add your proficiency bonus to any ability check you make using that tool.

That's what the proficiency does. It allows you to add a bonus to check you make using the tool. If you have no tool, you cannot use the tool, and cannot add your bonus to using it.
Xanathar's rules are optional, so changing this is up to the DM. In general you still need the tools for the special uses. The section intro says (p. 78):

This section offers various ways that tools can be used in the game.

It says it is talking about how tools can be used, not just tool proficiencies. But of course, the section is about proficiencies, and the rules here are ambiguous. The text under skill uses for example says

With respect to skills, the system is mildly abstract in terms of what a tool proficiency represents; essentially, it assumes that a character who has proficiency with a tool also has learned about facets of the trade or pro that are not necessarily associated with the use of the tool.

And some special uses clearly  have nothing to do with the tools. For example, Calligraphers Supplies are just 3 quills, some ink and parchments. It's not clear how any of these items could help you decipher a treasure map, yet that is the special use here.
When the rules say you do not "necessarily" need to tools for certain skill uses, I’d read this as "Ask your DM if they do". The whole point of these extended rules is to make tool proficiencies more generally useful. I'd err on the side of being generous in their interpretation.

XGTE makes it less clear cut. For example: "it assumes that a character who has proficiency with a tool also has learned about facets of the trade or profession that are not necessarily associated with the use of the tool."
Also, "This section offers various ways that tools can be used in the game." doesn't make it seem as if tool use is required, especially because we see what XTGE states (above quoted material).
As with most things, I think's up to DM discretion. But by RAW it seems you can use special use features without the tool, as it's only stated you need prof with the tool.

@Alterinam Yes, at least it us ambiguous for some of these uses. I don’ think that "This section offers various ways tools can be used" is (it is talking about using tools, not tool proficencies), but some if the uses seem unrelated in spite of that, and the statement on skill uses also softens it.
